# Headless selenium chromium/chrome downloads dont's run/save

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a script to download some PDF files to a folder on my computer. The script works perfectly, however, when this same script is run with the argument ("--headless") of chrome active, the files are no longer saved as usual.

I can't understand what this "headless" property is doing to prevent files from being saved.

Below is the code being used:
(No error is displayed when running the script.)

```
######### looping if ctrl+p
print("Setando configurações...")
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "isLandscapeEnabled": True,
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
    }
prefs = {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(settings),
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups" : 0,
    "savefile.default_directory": r'/home/file_name/directory_downloads/pdfs',# Para salvar com o 'headless' inativo
    "download.default_directory": r'/home/file_name/directory_downloads/pdfs', # Para salvar com o 'headless' ativo
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    }

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # Se ativo, salva os arquivos em um diretório desconhecido ou sobrepões arquivos salvos

print('Abrindo navegador...')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(dashObject.url)
driver.maximize_window()

print('Pausa para carregar o conteúdo da página')
sleep(7)
texto_xpath2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/a/span/span[3]').text
int_num_page2 = int(texto_navegacao_xpath2)

print('Preparando os arquivos PDFs...')
int_num_page = 1
while int_num_page <= int_num_page2:
    numero_pagina1 = str(int_num_page)

    driver.execute_script('window.print();')
    print(f'PDF da pagina {int_num_page} de {int_num_page2} OK')
    
    print('Proxima pagina...')
    xpath_next = '//*[@id="embedWrapperID"]/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/button[2]'
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_next).click()
    sleep(3)

    print("Mudando nome do arquivo...")
    pasta_download = pasta_pdfs + '/'
    arquivo_pdf = max([pasta_download + f for f in os.listdir(pasta_download)],key=os.path.getctime)
    shutil.move(arquivo_pdf,os.path.join(pasta_download,r"file_name"+ numero_pagina1 + dashUUID + ".pdf"))
    
    int_num_page += 1

print('Fechando navegador...')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: some servers may have system to detect selenium when it uses option `headless` and block it.

Comment: Certain scripts also don't run in headless mode. Typically the easy solution is to avoid headless.

Comment: this script will be executed in a site where the clients will download the files in PDF, for this reason the ideal would be that it worked with headless. Is there any other alternative for this function? (I tried to use a lib called pyvirtualdisplay but no success)

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by instantiating the lib pyvirtualdisplay before opening the code used to open the browser. tks for help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently with a download that worked in the regular mode and then stopped working in a headless mode.

The issue on my part was that, on regular mode, clicking on the download button opened a second tab on the browser (chrome), which usually (on regular mode) automatically closed after few seconds once the file was downloaded. The consequence of that behavior was that the active window briefly swiched from the first tab (the targetted webdriver) to the second opened tab (the downloading tab), then back to the first tab.

So on headless mode, the issue was that that second tab opened, BUT for some reason, didn't automatically closed when the download was over. So the active window (webdriver) remained the second tab. Because of that, it was unable to carry on the rest of the code (which is supposed to apply to the first tab).

Accordingly, for the headless mode to work, I had to expressly close the second tab and switch to the first tab in order for my code to carry on. Below an extract of that code :

```
while len(driver.window_handles) > 1: # if there are more than 1 tab
    time.sleep(5) # wait for download to finish or add a function that ensure the file is downloaded
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```